# Graphql schema code to view user profiles

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, aws-amplify, graphql-js

Am new to Graphql and actually following a tutorial. I am building a project in React Native and using AWS Amplify and Graphql for my backend. I needed a little change from the tutorial am following, I want users to be able to view user profile of other users in a their contact list just Instagram or Facebook.
In my schema.graphql I have the following code:

```js
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  imageUri: String
  username: String!
  email: String!
}
```

But I don't know the next code to write for user profile and the relationships for users to view other user user profiles.
I have been able to list contacts with the following code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUsers = async () => {
            try {

                const usersData = await API.graphql(
                    graphqlOperation(
                        listUsers
                    )
                )
                setUsers(usersData.data.listUsers.items);

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        fetchUsers();
    }, [])
```

Please I need guide on how to achieve viewing user profile when user is clicked on the contact list.

Comment: What does the `listUsers` query return? What is the type? I am not following where `items` comes from in the defined type provided by `users`. This is having me assume there is another type defined?

Kindly provide the code for `listUsers`.

Or am I missing the real question?

What is the relationship type-wise  for `users` and their followers?

Comment: I would imagine that `users` have a set of `followers` with their `ids`, those `ids` may be used to then perform a query that may take in a list of `ids` which the result would be a set/list of `user` types that would have the data listed at the beginning of your post.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add "auth" rule to your model

```
type User @model 
          @auth(
          rules: [

        #this is for logged-in user. cognito user is default for provider
       
        # In order to prevent private users from creating, another rule must be set for creating
        { allow: private, operations: [read] }
        # default provider is cognito
        { allow: private, provider: iam, operations: [read, create, update, delete] }
        # Only Owner can update its own data
        { allow: owner, ownerField: "username", operations: [update] }
    ]
)  {


      id: ID!
      name: String!
      imageUri: String
      username: String!
      email: String!
}
```

In the above code, I defined two auth rules. One is for Cognito user, he can only read, another one for the "iam" user who has more privileges.